# Error belongsTo en AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

tengo un error en la relacion belongsTo en la vista welcome, el error esel siguiente:

```
"Undefined property: stdClass::$work (View: ...\views\welcome.blade.php)"
```

Lo datos los recupero de la consulta realizada en AppServiceProvider ya que es comun en muchas vistas, lo curioso es que en el index del CRUD para la gestion funciona correctamente.

AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{

    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    // Cargo en todas las vistas el menu
    $workData = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM works');
    $eventData = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM events');

    View::share('dynamicWorks', $workData);
    View::share('dynamicEvents', $eventData);

}
```

Modelo Work y Event con las relaciones

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'work_id');
}

public function work()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Work', 'work_id');
}
```

Vista que no funciona

```
@foreach($dynamicEvents as $event)
<h4 class="media-heading">{{$event->work->title}}
    <small><i>{{$event->date}} a las {{$event->time}}</i></small>
</h4>@endforeach
```

Controlador que devuelve la vista que funciona

```
public function index()
{
    $events = Event::paginate(15);
    return view('events.index', compact('events'));
}
```

Vista que si funciona

```
@foreach($events as $event)
<tr>
    <td>{{$event->work->title}}</td>
</tr>@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La segunda vista funciona porque estás enviando un objeto y lo tratas como tal:

```
$event->work->title
```

La primera no funciona porque no está recibiendo un objeto, sino un array, y lo estás tratando como un objeto:

```
$event->work->title
```

Para solucionarlo tienes dos vías: Cambiar la consulta en AppServiceProvider y dejarla como en el Controlador. O, cambiar la lógica en la vista y tratar $even como un array.

Comment: Porque no funciona con view::shared? Es curioso, ya que tengo un menú que es común y funciona perfectamente con shared. Probaré esta opción, para el view::composer como se emplea en todas las vistas, sin llamarlas una a una, ya que por eso lo descarte inicialmente. Un saludo

Comment: Mucho más simple. La consulta que haces en el controlador te devuelve una Collection mientras que la que estás haciendo en em AppServiceProvider devuelve un array. En la primera vista estás tratando $even como un objeto y no lo es. Modifico la respuesta

Comment: Lo pruebo y doy por válida la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Asi funciona correctamente

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    $data = Work::all();
    $data2 = Event::all();
    View::share('globalWorks', $data);
    View::share('globalEvents', $data2);
}
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto! En cualquier caso mírate lo del view Composer; así mantendrás limpio el AppServiceProvider, lo tendrás todo centralizado y solo se calculará en las vistas que realmente lo necesiten.